# Can Firebase Cloud Functions Use an In-Memory Cache?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using [Firebase cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) for a project, and some of those functions fetch data from a firebase database.

I'd like to speed up some of these queries by leveraging a LRU cache, but it's not clear whether this is possible with Firebase cloud functions.

Does anyone know if the Firebase cloud functions have access to any kind of cache / semi-persistent memory access? Any help others can offer on this question would be hugely helpful!

Comment: as far as I know, it's not possible, functions are ephemeral, the closest I found was to my own instance of cloud memory store but I'm sure if this fits your use case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to share any sort of persistent data between function invocations, you will have to use another product, and code your function to use that.  Cloud Functions themselves only have immedaite access to the memory on the server instance that's running a particular invocation, and there could be many server instances all running functions at the same time.

If you're OK with maintaining a small local cache in memory on each instance, that's fine.  But you will have problem with this if you allow the cache to get so large that a function can't do its work with more limited memory.  You should also expect the cache to get reset whenever a server instances get deallocated, which happens outside of your control.

Since you're working in Google Cloud, consider using a product such as [Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/) to implement your cache.

Comment: Thanks very much! If I want to try a quick and dirty per-instance cache, can I reference the global namespace with `global`?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special to make a global.  Just declare it at the global scope and use it wherever you like in that file.

Comment: Oh wow, awesome! I think I'm already on board with the Redis product but this is good to know!

Comment: if you see this, I have a quick follow up--how much RAM are Firebase cloud function instances allocated? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Unfortunate that firebase SDK doesn't have caching option at query level, firebase team should do that with extra pricing also fine