# Perform one-time setup in a Firebase Cloud Function that is always running

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a server side task that I am trying to move to a Firebase Cloud Functions. I have a set of users registered with the app. Each user has a mobile number. The task is, given a set of mobile numbers, find the users who are registered with the app. Currently, I maintain an in-memory map of all the users and can quickly figure out whether a mobile number is registered by doing a lookup in the map.

Now with Gen 2 Cloud Functions, I can create a function with higher memory and concurrency and also keep the function running which will allow avoid cold-starts. But I want to perform the setup where I create the map of users only once. Is there a recommended way of doing this setup only one for a function that is always running.

One way I can think of is to have a flag and only do the setup when the flag is not set but I am not sure if that is the right way. Below is what I was thinking:

```
let cacheCreated = false
let contactsCache = new Cache()

exports.findContacts = onCall({minInstances: 1, maxInstances: 1, memory: '16GiB', concurrency: 1000 }, async (request) => {
  if (!request.auth) {
    console.error('The function must be called while authenticated.')
    // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
    throw new HttpsError(
      'permission-denied',
      'The function must be called while authenticated.'
    )
  }

  if(!cacheCreated) {
    cacheCreated = true
    createCache()
  }

  // handle the task
})
```

Please let me know if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: I guess this probably won't work as the `cacheCreated` will be false for each function invocation even though the function is always running. I don't think I can define it globally also as I have many other functions also which are not always running and they may trigger the cache creation process on each start. Please note that there are ~3 million users in the Firebase Realtime Database (it is stored in Realtime Database due to legacy reasons), and I can't keep loading the cache. Please let me know if there is a to achieve what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you try using `Realtime database` with this code https://codefile.io/f/PQ7Y4BvkA6. This approach performs individual lookups in the database for each mobile number and avoids the need to load the entire user cache into memory. It ensures that you can handle a large number of users efficiently.

Comment: This may heavily rack up the Firebase Realtime Database downloads cost as it it trying to download the whole users branch on each function invocation, right?

Comment: I have updated the code to use global variables to keep track of whether the cache has been created or not. The cache itself is only created in the `findContacts` function due to which it will not affect the other functions. Is this a good approach?

Comment: Can you have a look at this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71843109/18265702).

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni My question is not so much about how to lookup users but how to setup a long-lasting cache in Firebase Cloud Functions which are always running.

Comment: Please check with this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59537105/18265702).